# How to test for the value of a "global" variable set by GPIO interrupt downwards in the program

Tags: python

I want to use a variable "lifeflag" that is set to 1 by GPIO interrupt and is cleared in the block "if pin=="1" ...."

Then, when pin becomes =2 from elsewhere in the program, the code "if lifeflag==1" shall be executed in the block "if pin=="2".

The error is thrown "lifeflag has not been assigned a value upon starting the program". (The block if pin=="1" has not necessarily been executed.)

Tried to add "lifeflag=0" somewhere at the top of the program -including "global" or not- 
I still get the error "local variable lifeflag referenced before assignment.

Is there any solution to get this working?

```
import RPi.GPIO as rpigpio
rpigpio.setmode(rpigpio.BCM)
rpigpio.setup(6, rpigpio.IN, pull_up_down=rpigpio.PUD_UP) 

def my_callback(channel): 
    lifeflag=1
    print("lifeflag=",lifeflag)

rpigpio.add_event_detect(6, rpigpio.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)
```

.....

```
    if pin == "1" :
        print(pin)
    lifeflag=0
```

.....

```
    if pin == "2" :
        ret,frame=cam.read()
        cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)
        print("237=",pin)
        rpigpio.output(20,rpigpio.HIGH)

        if lifeflag == 1:
            print("247=")
            rpigpio.output(20,rpigpio.LOW)
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is properly indented? When code execution reaches your very first print-statement `print("lifeflag=",lifeflag)`, the error occurs because there is no variable with that name.

Comment: Sorry, just corrected the identation. The print belongs to the callback function.

Comment: You might want to do the things you tried again, since they are important. Set lifeflag to some value right at the top and add `global lifeflag` as the first line in the callback. I assume that it is the `lifeflag == 1` line that throws the error, right?

Comment: This does not work either. I have "global lifeflag" near the top and just beneath put "lifeflag=1" but then getting the error "in main,  local variable "lifeflag" referenced before assignement". The same if I add "global lifeflag" to the callback function.

Comment: Looks like Python doesn't know "real" global variables. Solved my problem by using a GPIO output as a flag - GPIOs are really global and can be read and set anywhere in the program.